# How to assign a POSIXlt element to a vector

Tags: r, vector, posixlt

I have a column of date-time variables `ex`, which I want to randomly sample one element from and assign it to a vector. However, I don't get the result if I do:

```
> sample(ex,1)
[1] "2017-12-24 10:42:39 GMT"
> some_vector<-rep(NA,1)
> some_vector[1]<-sample(ex,1)
Warning message:
In some_vector[1] <- sample(ex, 1) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
> some_vector
[[1]]
[1] 20
```

Example `POSIXlt` `ex`

```
structure(list(sec = c(39, 31, 12, 20), min = c(42L, 44L, 13L, 
22L), hour = c(10L, 10L, 15L, 15L), mday = c(24L, 24L, 14L, 14L
), mon = c(11L, 11L, 0L, 0L), year = c(117L, 117L, 118L, 118L
), wday = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), yday = c(357L, 357L, 13L, 13L), 
    isdst = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), zone = c("GMT", "GMT", "GMT", 
    "GMT"), gmtoff = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_)), .Names = c("sec", "min", "hour", "mday", "mon", 
"year", "wday", "yday", "isdst", "zone", "gmtoff"), class = c("POSIXlt", 
"POSIXt"))
```

I want to get `some_vector` output as

```
some_vector
[1] "2017-12-24 10:42:39 GMT"
```

Comment: it works for me if I remove the `rep(NA,1)` and just type `some_vector<-NA`

Comment: You can’t assign POSIXlt to a vector but you can with POSIXct. Would that be OK?

Comment: yep..works for `some_vector <- sample(as.POSIXct(ex), 1)`

Comment: I found a way -- I can just convert ex to character, then I can assign without any changes.